# Filter based on multiple tags in aws secretsmanager data source

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-secrets-manager

I need to get list of secrets in data block , I want to get list of secrets which satisfy **both tag value** i,e ClusterID and provider.
But current behavior  is I get secrets wherein if they match any one of the tag.
Required: we want secrets if they match both tags

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secrets" "fetch_secrets" {

  filter {
    name   = "tag-value"
    values = ["${var.ClusterID}","${var.provider}"]
  }
}
```

aws_secretsmanager_secrets datablock **doesn't** accept tags , nameprefix , lifecycle block

Comment: And what is the key for the `var.ClusterID` and `var.provider` tags? So it's usually `somekey = tagvalue`, are there any keys for those tag values you provide?

Comment: tag-name = provider
tag-value = aws

tag-name  = clusterID
tag-value = clusterName1

Answer (score 2):

In this situation you would need a separate `filter` block for each tag to ensure an intersection, and not a union:

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secrets" "fetch_secrets" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag-value"
    values = [var.ClusterID]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag-value"
    values = [var.provider]
  }
}
```

The `value` parameter allows any match, whereas the filters combine to mandate a match against all filters.

Comment: I tried but this is doing union not intersection . if secret has any one of the tag , it is appearing in the result :( . 
Is there any other way .
I can filter based on clusterid , and then can we do some for and string match opration for provider , as my secret name consists of provider name
eg: sm/<clusterid>/<provider_name>
i want to store this in a local variable where i can consume later

Comment: @niranjanpb You would then need the `setintersection` function, but we would then also need to see your data attribute usage to assist further.

Comment: data "aws_secretsmanager_secrets" "fetch_secrets" {
filter {
name   = "tag-key"
values = ["clusterid"]
}
filter {
name   = "tag-value"
values = ["azure"]
}
}

locals{
metadata = {
    az_key = data.aws_secretsmanager_secrets.fetch_secrets.names
 }
}


resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "metadata" {
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.provider_metadata.id
  secret_string = jsonencode(local.metadata)
}

Answer (score 0):

Through testing with the AWS CLI, it currently seems there is no direct way to filter on a given tag (key-value pair) or tags; that is, the filters perform a union (as mentioned) and also are not tag-wise and don't combine well.

I curated a module to encapsulate this complexity (annoyance):

```
//./modules/facets/msk-scram-secrets/...

//local.tf
data aws_secretsmanager_secrets scram_users_by_name {
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["AmazonMSK_"]
  }
}

data aws_secretsmanager_secret scram_users {
  for_each = { for secret in data.aws_secretsmanager_secrets.scram_users_by_name.names : secret => secret }

  name = each.key
}

locals {
  scram_secrets_arns = [
    for name, secret in data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.scram_users : secret.arn if alltrue([for k, v in var.tags: try(secret.tags[k], "!!!EXCLUDE") == v])
  ]
}

// variables.tf
variable tags {
  description = "Tags to select secrets by; all must be present"
  type        = map(string)
}


//outputs.tf
output arns {
  value = local.scram_secrets_arns
}

//meta.tf
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.4"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 5.1.0"
    }
  }
}
```

My use-case is provisioning an MSK cluster: I want to *discover* secrets to associate for SASL/SCRAM user authentication, hence the `AmazonMSK_` name-prefix; and within that discovery I only want to associate secrets/users tha are appropriately tagged.

This module would then be used as follows:

```
module msk_scram_secrets {
  source = "./modules/facets/msk-scram-secrets"

  tags = {
    "your-org.io/environment-tenant"  = <customer-id>
    "your-org.io/environment-token"   = <environment-uid>
    "your-org.io/environment-purpose" = <project-name>
  }
}
```

Where this does not create any resources - it just uses data-sources - you can test it out using just `terraform refresh` and `terraform output`